# Importing files into my java path

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, fantom

I'm writing a web app in Fantom using the F4 IDE and I want to integrate some of google calendars features into the app. I see some videos of how to use the google api in Eclipse, but I can't get that method to work in F4.

Can anybody enlighten me as to how to add the google API to work in F4 IDE?

This is a fairly important part of the app, so I really need to get this working.

Thanks,

Comment: More information would be useful... Which API? What calendar features? What videos? Which method? Is it F4 that's the problem? Is there a stack trace? What libraries are you using? 

Currently your question is as informative as "My car won't start, can anybody help?"

Comment: Haha that's fair. We want to use the google Calendar API, and essentially we want to recreate the calendar in a different app, so users will be able to input data into the calendar from their calendar. We need to import the Google Calendar and Google API libraries but are unsure how to do that.

Comment: If you place .jar files in `%FAN_HOME%/lib/java/ext` they should get picked up by F4 in the library 'Fantom Native Libraries (Java)' - is that what you mean?

Comment: Well, as long as your F4 Fantom interpreter is pointing to the Fantom installation in `%FAN_HOME%` - see http://www.fantomfactory.org/articles/intro-to-f4#addingAnInterpreter